# Ошибка в PHP "Object of a class couldn't be converted to a string"

Tags: php

Всем привет! Столкнулся со странной для меня ошибкой, имеется код:

```
class DB {
    ...
}

$db = new DB;

class MyClass {
    private $db;

    function __construct {
        global $db;

        //Пытаюсь взять объект $db по ссылке, чтобы не прописывать для каждой функции global $db
        $this->$db =& $db; //Здесь получаю ошибку "Object of a class DB couldn't be converted to a string"
    }
    ...
}
```

Подскажите, в чём моя ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в записи `$this->$db`. В данном случае `->$db` обозначает доступ к свойству объекта с именем, содержащимся в переменной `$db` (если провести аналогию с массивами? то `$this[$db]`).

Вам же нужно  заменить эту строку на простое `$this->db = &$db;`

зы: не используйте `global` переменную. передавайте подключение в качестве параметра конструктора  `__construct($db)`